# Semantic-UI field botton margin broken in wide screens

Tags: css, semantic-ui

I have a form with some fields. when I resize the browser window, the distance between the fields is broken. I do not know what to do to keep the distance between the always the same fields. If you access the link below, you can see it happening in the 3,4,5 fields to resize the Result window:

http://jsfiddle.net/Lj3w4z3m/1/

```
<div class='ui form '>
<div class='fields'>
    <div class='eight wide field'>
        <label>field 1</label>
        <input name='Status' type='text' value='Enviado para a junta' readonly='readonly'>
    </div>
    <div class='eight wide field'>
        <label>field 2</label>
        <input name='ProximoStatus' type='text' value='Retorno da junta' readonly='readonly'>
    </div>
</div>
<div class='fields'>
    <div class='sixteen wide field'>
        <label>field 3</label>
        <input name='Observacao' type='text' value=''>
    </div>
</div>
<div class='fields'>
    <div class='sixteen wide field'>
        <label>field 4</label>
        <input name='Observacao' type='text' value=''>
    </div>
</div>
<div class='fields'>
    <div class='sixteen wide field'>
        <label>field 5</label>
        <input name='Observacao' type='text' value=''>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the fiddle. Please, check it out. I think this will solve your problem.

`<div class='ui form '>
    <div class='fields'>
        <div class='eight wide field'>
            <label>field 1</label>
            <input name='Status' type='text' value='Enviado para a junta' readonly='readonly'>
        </div>
        <div class='eight wide field'>
            <label>field 2</label>
            <input name='ProximoStatus' type='text' value='Retorno da junta' readonly='readonly'>
        </div>
        <div class='sixteen wide field'>
            <label>field 3</label>
            <input name='Observacao' type='text' value=''>
        </div>
        <div class='sixteen wide field'>
            <label>field 4</label>
            <input name='Observacao' type='text' value=''>
        </div>
        <div class='sixteen wide field'>
            <label>field 5</label>
            <input name='Observacao' type='text' value=''>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>`